# JSTL: Dynamic number currency, change the pattern and keep it dynamic?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to show a currency dynamicly, that works totally fine!

But I'd like to change the pattern from "SFr. 150'000.00" to "150'000.00 SFr." (and still keep it dynamicly!)

Any suggestions how I could do that?

Here is the code:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />


<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${investVolume}" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${investVolume}" currencySymbol="SFr."/>`

Comment: That would not help, I wanna keep the currency Symbol dynamicly...

so that if it would be Dollars it would show up "$" instead of "SFr."

Comment: You can use a variable in the currencySymbol attribute. It is evaluated at request time.

Comment: Ye that's not the problem, I just want to change the pattern, that the currency symbol is behind the value not in front of it

Comment: mm It always shows behind in my apps... Might be caused by that `setLocale`

Comment: hmm okay so what would you suggest?

Comment: Did the currently accepted answer solve your concrete problem? Based on its comments, I have the impression of not, but yet it's accepted, so I'm somewhat confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${investVolume}" pattern="###,###.## ¤"/>
```

The pattern attribute follows [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) rules.

The `¤` in the pattern represents the currency symbol.

Although I'm not sure if that `'` would show in an upper or lower position this should be the way to go.

Comment: I wish that this would change my problem but like that the country pattern would be over written...

with your pattern it would look that way: "150000.00 SFr."
with the dynamic pattern it would look that way: "SFr. 150'000.00"

Comment: :/ I'm sorry then but dont think there is any specific tag for that. You'll have to force it by showing the numeric value as a normal type, and concatenating the currency symbol.

Comment: There are always different patterns for any kind of currency values, that's my problem... as an example Germany formats their values like that: 150.000,00 Switzerland Formats it that way: 150'000.00 This difference from each country is very confusing thought so

Comment: Yes but have you actually tried it? The description for the `,` in the pattern says "Serves as a placeholder for a grouping separator." so it might apply the locale...

Comment: sadly it then shows up totally disformatted ("150'000 ÂSFr.") ... But i Have to check on that one, thanks

Comment: Is your page in UTF-8? The weird `¤` symbols is unicode (\u00A4)